# Use JavaScript to dynamically change an image in HTML when a var updates

Tags: javascript, html, image

I know this is a simple question but I am missing something. I am trying to update an image on a web page when a variable updates. I have tried several things and nothing is working. Here is what I have currently:

```js
var sup_fan_state = 1;

function sup_fan_1(sup_fan_status) {
  if (sup_fan_state === 0) {
    document.getElementById('sup_fan_status').src = "images/fan00_250_gray_grad.png";
  } else if (sup_fan_state === 1) {
    document.getElementById('sup_fan_status').src = "images/sup_fan.gif";
  } else {
    window.alert("Something went terribly wrong!");
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="images/blank.png" alt="supply fan" id="sup_fan_status" name="sup_fan_status">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And when you using this code ?

Comment: The function is declared with a parameter, but the parameter is not used.

Comment: I am trying to use the function to update the <img> tag but I do not know how to connect the dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var statuses = {
 '0' : 'http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_66072_400x400.png',
 '1' : 'http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_62417_400x400.png',
 '' : 'http://piq.codeus.net/static/media/userpics/piq_65453_400x400.png'
};

function changeFanStatus() {
 var status = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]['fanState'].value;
 if (!statuses[status]) {
  return alert("Something went terribly wrong!");
 }
 document.getElementById('sup_fan_status').src = statuses[status];
}
```

```html
<form>
 <input type="radio" name="fanState" value="0" onclick="changeFanStatus()" />0N
 <br />
 <input type="radio" name="fanState" value="1" onclick="changeFanStatus()" />OFF
 <br />
 <input type="radio" name="fanState" value="" onclick="changeFanStatus()" /> Other
 <br />
 <input type="radio" name="fanState" value="undefined" onclick="changeFanStatus()" /> undefined
</form>
<img src="" alt="supply fan" id="sup_fan_status" name="sup_fan_status" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Though I am able to run this example in a web browser, I am unable to modify this to use this solution in my work. I need to control the image src based on the value of a variable coming from a Carel controller.

Comment: Let me know, how i could help you with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution. Though I was unable to use Thirueswaran's solution, it got me thinking about where I needed to be. 
The variable values are coming from a Carel controller and I am using them to put animation on a monitor. I could not figure out how to extract the variable value from the controller and then pass it to a function. Here is what worked:

```js
function getVariables() {

// calls function changeFanStatus and passes variable value
document.getElementById("sup_fan_status").src = changeFanStatus(digitals[1]);
// more variables

// refresh all vars every 5 sec without page refresh
timer=setTimeout('getVariables()',5000);
}

// set image source
function changeFanStatus(state)
{
  img_src = "images/fan00_250_gray_grad.png";
  if(state==0) img_src = "images/fan00_250_gray_grad.png";
  if(state==1) img_src = "images/sup_fan.gif";
  return  img_src;
}
```

```html
<img id="sup_fan_status" alt="supply fan" class="sup_fan1" src="images/blank.png">
```